# Translation of "bed bug" (chinche?)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, animales, vocabulario

In English, [bed bugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedbug) are parasitic insects that can infest beds and the areas where people sleep. Wikipedia shows that the Spanish term for bed bug is [chinche](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cimex_lectularius). However, my understanding is that *chinche* (at least in Central America) refers to the insect that spreads [Chagas disease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chagas_disease).

What are the correct terms for these two insects, and how can you make the (very important!) difference clear when talking about them?

Comment: Common names are fine if you and your speaker agree on them; if not, better use the scientific names first as the accepted answer suggests. Note that Chagas disease vectors have many common names; in Argentina, Chile, Uruguay and Bolivia (i.e. a large tract of Spanish-speaking South America) they're known as *vinchucas*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both bed bugs and the insects that spread the protozoan that causes Chagas disease are insects of the order *Hemiptera*. Bugs of this order are commonly referred to in Spanish as *chinches*, so this is a good name for either.

So yes, both bugs are closely related. If you want to differentiate, you can always be specific (or pedantic!) and use their scientific names; [*Triatominae*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triatominae) (or triatomines) for the Chagas disease vector and [*Cimex*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cimex) for bed bugs.